# Can you update the number of sections in a UITableView after CellForRowAt?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm new to Swift so please bear with me. I've got a program which uses a JSOn file which is decoded into the following

```
struct Artwork: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let title: String
    let artist: String
    var location: String }
```

after I call my cellForRowAt method a unique location is stored in a locationArray (when printed this is correct) , and the table reflects this when run, however when I try and use numberOfSections method and return locationArray.count no data is shown in the table and no sections are created, if I run a print line in numberOfSections the locationArray is empty. Is there a way to call numberOfSections after cellForRowAt? or am I approaching the problem wrong form the outset?

Comment: The array is your data source, it should have something in it before you try to display the elements in a table view.  If you want to reflect changes in the array, addition or deletion, you can use tableView.reloadData() to force the table view to display them.

Comment: @l3owman you should never call cellForRowAt

Comment: You don't call this function the tableview does. You should not modify your source data (number of rows/sections) in `cellForRow(at:)` since this function can be called multiple times for the same row and the order of rows for which it is called is not guaranteed.

Comment: sorry I think my wording is letting me down here, so the data in the cell is derived from the JSON and in the cellForRow method I set the text to =. cell.textLabel?.text = art?.artworks[indexPath.row].title ?? "no title"  which I'm guessing works correctly because my data shows, in my numberOfSection method what would be the easiest way to return unique locations as a count so I can split the titles by location?

Answer (score 0):

when you hook up a tableview delegate + datasource you need 2 specific delegates in order for it to run.

If you want to update a particular row with say new data you would have to do these steps:

1. grab arraymodel data

   var dataFromArray = self.exampleArray[Int]
2. add any data that you need or need to replace

   var dataFromArray.name = "joe smith"
3. reload the specific row where is being represented by said model from array

   tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: Int, section: Int)], with: .none)

## numberOfRowsInSection

-If you have 5 models in your array, the 'cellforrowat' method will get called 5 times

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.exampleArray.count
}
```

## CellForRowAt

-for each cell you need to be created here is where you can set up the data dynamically based off the 'indexpath'

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { 

  let dataFromArray = self.exampleArray[indexPath.row]

  return UITableViewCell()
}
```

Comment: how do I then split the data into sections once these methods are complete?